# Graphics is not a primitive or directive- please help!

Tags: graphics, programming

[image: A Screenshot of my code]

I cannot seem to draw a windmill that fits in the photo background. Any help is appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: Post code not images if you want help.

Comment: @BobHanlon truthfully, the posting of the picture makes this simple to diagnose.

Comment: You never executed `drawWindmill`, so it has no value. (The blue color tells you this.) Hence, it is not a `Graphics` primitive.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**

```
(*background*)
background = {LightBlue, Rectangle[{4, 2}, {-2, -6}]};

(*sun*)
sun = {Yellow, Disk[]};

(*windmill*)
windmill = {Blue, Thickness[.02], Opacity[.15], JoinForm @ "Round", 
   Table[Rotate[
     BezierCurve[{{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {-1, 0}}, SplineClosed -> True], 
     r Degree], {r, 0, 345, 15}]};

(*process*)
Graphics[Join[{{background}, {sun}, {windmill}}]]
```

**Output:**

[image: output example]

Comment: All you need is `Graphics[{background, sun, windmill}]`

Comment: I agree. I did not modify the code from op. The above only shows that the code and its associated output.